# Solving a specific Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I go about solving this differential equation:
$$ y'+ y = \frac{2xe^{-x}}{{1+ye^x}} $$

My lecturer mentions changing it into a separable equation but I am not sure how. Other methods are also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'+ y = \frac{2xe^{-x}}{{1+ye^x}}$$
Substitute $w=ye^x+1$ then:
$$w'=y'e^x+ye^x=e^x(y+y')$$
The DE is separable.
$$w'w=2x$$

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint}:$

$$\frac{2x}{1+ye^x} = y'e^x + ye^x = (ye^x)'$$